# Qml delegate index belongs to who?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I want to know to who the `index` role belongs to. `ListModel`, `ListView` or others? How to test it?

```
ListModel{ 
    id:testModel

    ListElement{ 
        //  ....
    }

    //  ....
}

ListView{

    model:testModel

    delegate: 
        Column {
        Label{
            text:index
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Read carefully the section "Models" of [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html), especially the first part. Note also that, in the [attached properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#properties) of `ListView` there's no `index` role. Those are basically the answers you are searching for. I second @Mitch on the question: what do exactly you wanna do?

Comment: He's asking about `index` property within a delegate and that property is exposed indeed: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop

Answer (score 0):

The `index` property is exposed to the delegate by means of the `ListView`. That property is an `int`, so it's probably passed by copy and you won't interfere with the attachee's logic by modifying it. For the `delegate` is a component handled by the `ListView`, you can safely suppose that the `index` property belongs to the latter and reflects a feature due to the provided model.

What does it mean "how to test it"?